# How to get URL for application's document directory iPhone

Tags: iphone

This code is a part of Core Data. The URLsForDirectory....method does not run on iOS < 4 so I need to know some other methods/objects to call. I would also appriciate documentation for future reference. Thank you

```
/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
*/
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Do you need a URL, or just the document path?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can get the document path via the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` [foundation function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) as follows:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will work on iOS 2+.

Comment: @Andreas No problem. Hope it all goes well. :-)

Comment: How can you get this as a NSURL instead of a string?

Comment: to get from documentsPath to NSURL: `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];` make sure that your string ends in a `/` if the url specifies a directory.

Answer (score 51):

An alternative solution would be to use the [`-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:) method and fetching the path from the returned NSArray:

Objective-C:

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentsURL = [paths lastObject];
```

Swift:

```
let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let documentsURL = paths[0] as! NSURL
```

This is supported in iOS 4.0+

Comment: Why are you accessing the `lastObject` in ObjC and `[0]` aka `firstObject` in Swift? Just asking of interest...

Comment: `paths.first` will return an optional. For the sake of simplicity, the subscript accessor is used here so we don't have to deal with type casing and optional unwrapping.

Comment: `- [NSArray firstObject]` and `- [NSArray lastObject]` are defined identically. The implementation does not say anything on a difference. Can you provide more background?

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert, we are assuming that there is only one url for the directory. Under that assumption, you can use `first` or `last` interchangeably in this case, but the return type will be a `URL?` by [function definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689973-last), likely requiring you to unwrap. On the other hand, using the subscript accessor returns a nonnull `URL` [by definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540606-subscript) as long as there is an element at that index (otherwise you will have an out of bounds runtime error).

Answer (score 20):

Swift 3

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Swift 2.2 version:

```
let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let filePath = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("filename")
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting iOS 16.0 you can use:

```
URL.documentsDirector
```

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3988456-documentsdirectory/)

Comment: It's `URL.documentsDirectory`.