# About NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

Tags: iphone, ios

I hv spent quite a while but no luck on following question:

I tried to access Document directory.

Both following codes work perfectly. Could someone tell me whats the difference between
    last object and     objectAtIndex:0

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths lastObject];
```

or

```
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

The most close question was [How to get URL for application's document directory iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608091/how-to-get-url-for-applications-document-directory-iphone), but it didn't explain the difference between lastObject and objectAtIndex:0.

I have read thru Apple Developer Library. It only says 'The directory returned by this method may not exist. This method simply gives you the appropriate location for the requested directory. Depending on the application’s needs, it may be up to the developer to create the appropriate directory and any in between.' Someone please help, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there is no difference between `[searchPaths lastObject]` and `[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0]`, because `searchPaths` contains only one entry.  The user domain only contains one document directory.

If you try this you'll get different results:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSApplicationDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
```

Answer (score 0):

`searchPaths` may contain more than one directory if you look with `NSAllDomainsMask`.

Since Xcode 5, best practice is:

```
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths firstObject];
```