# iOS: Tabs and document directory

Tags: ios, tabs, directory, document

I am writing an app with four tabs. In the second tab I am storing data in a plist and use this code to set the path:

```
//get the path to the documents directory (where we will store our plist)
NSString* docDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

//append the path to the documents diretory with our plist name
NSString* destPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"surveyResults.plist"];
```

It is in it's own method. Works fine.

In the fourth tab I placed the same code, but I get an error on the [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]:

```
No visible @interface for 'FourthViewController' declares the selector 'applicationDocumentsDirectory'
```

I have it in the viewDidLoad method.

Any reason it works on one tab and not another?

Comment: have you implement the: applicationDocumentsDirectory in your FourthViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using the code from this post:

[How to get URL for application's document directory iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608091/how-to-get-url-for-applications-document-directory-iphone)

You just need to ensure that the ViewController for your fourth tab also includes this code snippet also, I expect you've just forgotten to put it in.

Personally I'd place such a method in a helper class, and mark it as a static method so I can call it with, e.g. [MyHandyUtils applicationDocumentsDirectory].

Comment: No, I wasn't using the code you linked to. I am going to use a singleton to get and store the directory path but I was curious as to why I was getting this error message.