# Unable to copy file from bundle to Documents directory, why does fileExistsAtPath return error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsfilemanager

I'm using the following snippet of code to attempt to copy a file from my application resources directory into the Documents area. I have used the below from the [PocketOCR](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR) project on Github :

```
// Set up the tessdata path. This is included in the application bundle
    // but is copied to the Documents directory on the first run.
    NSString *dataPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"Datapath is %@", dataPath);
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath ]) {
        NSLog(@"File didn't exist at datapath...");
        // get the path to the app bundle (with the tessdata dir)
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *tessdataPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
        if (tessdataPath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:NULL];
        }
    }
```

This is the output I get from invoking the above :

> 2012-06-06 14:53:42.607 MyApp[1072:707] Datapath is
>   /var/mobile/Applications/9676D920-D6D1-4F86-9177-07CC3247A124/Documents/tessdata
>   Error opening data file
>   /var/mobile/Applications/9676D920-D6D1-4F86-9177-07CC3247A124/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata

I have the eng.traineddata file located in my xcode project like so

It appears that the Error is being reported when attempting to check if `fileExistsAtPath`, I wouldn't expect this to throw an error, but to either return YES or NO.

Is there an easier way to copy the `eng.traineddata` file across, or have I made a mistake which can be corrected here?

[image: I have the eng.traineddata file located in my xcode project like so]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSString *dataPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
NSLog(@"Datapath is %@", dataPath);

// If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] == NO)
    {
        NSString *tessdataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eng" ofType:@"traineddata"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];

    }


-(NSString*) applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    // Get the documents directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    return docsDir;
}
```

Comment: what the hell is [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]? Missing / incomplete code?

Comment: incomplete code, a common method to wrap the path lookup code, see for an example (though returning NSURL in this case)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608091/how-to-get-url-for-applications-document-directory-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I hope also help this code to copy all type of file bundle to Document directory folder ..

```
NSString *pathsToReources = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *yourOriginalDatabasePath = [pathsToReources stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lunchDB.sqlite"];  // file name u want copy 

NSArray *pathsToDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathsToDocuments objectAtIndex: 0];


    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lunchDB.sqlite"];  // file name & your original path (Document path)

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath: dbPath]) {

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: yourOriginalDatabasePath toPath: dbPath error: NULL] != YES)

NSAssert2(0, @"Fail to copy database from %@ to %@", yourOriginalDatabasePath, dbPath);

}
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` of `NSFileManager` and specify that the path is a directory, because it is.

Answer (score 0):

`stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"`

The line above required that tessdata is a physical folder (a blue color folder), not a group (yellow folder as you are showing) in Xcode project. Create a folder in your Xcode project folder using the Finder and then in Xcode drag and drop the folder to your project and select the folder reference when asked.