# write to plist - error

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I am new to iOS. I have a plist that contains:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>MsgTest</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Order</key>
            <string>Value</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I do want to change the

`NSString @"Value"` with : `NSString *result=@"Alphabetic".`
I did the following:

```
     plistOrder = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PList" ofType:@"plist"];
        orderDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistOrder] mutableCopy];
        SettingArray = [[orderDictionary objectForKey:@"MsgTest"]mutableCopy];

    [SettingMutableDictionary setValue:result forKey:@"Order"];
            [SettingMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:SettingDictionary];

             [orderDictionary setValue:SettingArray forKey:@"MsgTest"];

            BOOL success= [orderDictionary writeToFile:plistOrder atomically:YES];
            if (success){
                NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!success");
            }
```

but the bool success is NO. Why? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

The plist in which I want to change data is in Resource folder.

Comment: You are trying to write a file into application bundle - which is read-only. You can save it do Documents folder. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5608107/653513

Comment: The dictionary you show does not have a `Settings` property (besides the problem already mentioned).