# Swift: writeToFile does not save file on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, file, swift

I have a string I read from a text file:
`text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!`.
Using `println(text)` I get the output "some text".

Now I also have another string `otherSting = "other text"`. What I want to do is save this text to the text file. I tried using `otherText.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)` and then reading the text file again. When trying on the iOS Simulator I get the output I expected: "other text". But when executing the same app on my iPhone i still get "some text". Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I also tried using `otherText.writeToURL(url!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)`with the same results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you post the complete sequence of what you are doing, with log statements and their output.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the old text, you are clearly reading the old file. Make sure you have two different `path` or `url` variables.

What happened most likely is that you saved to file1, tried to overwrite that same file1 which failed silently, so that file1 contains the original data.

Also, as Paulw has pointed out, you cannot write to your bundle. Instead you have to copy files to the [application documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5608107/427083) first, or create them there.

Comment: Yes what I am trying to do is overwriting the original file. So the path variable hast to be the same because it is the same file I want to read from, but the second time it should have the new data in it.

Comment: Remove the file first if it exists, using `fileExistsAtPath` to check and `removeItemAtPath` to remove it. These are `NSFileManager` APIs.

Comment: So I should first remove it and then create another one? why can't I just overwrite the first one?

Comment: Ok I tried removing the first file and then saving the new one at the same path. same results

Comment: What is "path"? Is it a file in your bundle?  If so you can't write to it.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it is! ok so where would I have to put it? and how?